# user profile services set as running, but manual synch won't start

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

After years of good performance the UPS stopped performing.

The services are listed as running but starting a manual sync has got no effects. Even the night sync apparently does not perform, although it is tracked as effective.

**FIM** throws a `MOSS deltaimport` and MOSS export with a stopped-extension-dll-load`enter code here`.

The latter started 5 days ago, we did not perform any update/upgrade/change

SP 2013 on premise

Comment: What ULS logs and Event Logs saying about it. Did you try to stop and Start the Sync Services and also Reset IIS on Sync Server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 2013 but I had the same issue in 2010.  I found this link very helpful.  Basically I had to replace a couple of .dll files.

[TechNet Article HERE](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0e253f5b-38b5-4112-97f9-1cead7d754ac/problem-with-user-profile-syncronization-export-to-ad)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, clear the configuration cache following this guide
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

The User profile service started to sync again